# Flutter Convert date time to string failed midnight

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert date and time to string with below code but when I convert the below
2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 I get 01-09-2020 24:00 that is wrong

```
      String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm').format(date);
```

the correct is 01-09-2020 00:00 how can I get this

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy kk:mm').format(date);
```

I have no idea what "kk" is as a format string, but you seem to want "HH" for "hours":

```
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm').format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please try this, it's work for me :
>
> ```
> DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm').format(DateTime.parse("2020-09-01 00:00:00.000"))
> ```
>
> The two formats essentially do the same thing but differ in how they
> handle midnight. kk will format midnight to 24:00 whereas HH will
> format to 00:00. The hours in a day in k are 1-24 and in H are 0-23